# How do I Autolink or add links to Facebook API posts

Tags: javascript, c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the Facebook SDK for .Net http://facebooksdk.net/.
The query I am running against the Facebook API returns a list of posts that a public user has made. 
The results for the query return are in plain text.

**How do I update the URLs and Hashtags so that they are automatically wrapped in links (a href) so that they can be clicked?**

For twitter I've used https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/js

This is my code:

```
var client = new FacebookClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appToken"]);
dynamic response = client.Get("somePublicUser?fields=posts.limit(1){message}");
var post = response.posts.data[0].message;
```

The message content is: "Happy #WorldTheatreDay! \n\nWhat's the best show you've ever seen?"

I'd love to see it be something like: ""Happy #[WorldTheatreDay](https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/WorldTheatreDay)! \n\nWhat's the best show you've ever seen?"

Comment: Can you post the code that you've used, and show us some sample data so that we can better assist you?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the Twitter JavaScript tool: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/js

And just replacing Twitter's URLs for Facebooks alternate versions.

```
twttr.txt.autoLink("Click this link http://www.google.com", {
    hashtagUrlBase: "https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/",
    usernameUrlBase: "https://www.facebook.com/",
    listUrlBase: "https://www.facebook.com/"
});
```